# Python 3.7 | Вывод данных из таблицы

Tags: python-3.x, текст, table

друзья!

Подскажите, пожалуйста ...
Есть СПИСОК (импортированный из ***.txt):

```
742     Ветеринарные услуги
763     Сельско-хозяйственные кооперативные общества
780     Ландшафтные и садоводческие магазины
1520    Генеральные подрядчики - жилищное и торговое строительство
1711    Генеральные подрядчики по вентиляции, теплоснабжению, и водопроводу
1731    Подрядчики по электричеству
1740    Изоляция, мозаика, штукатурные работы, каменная кладка, облицовка плиткой
```

В консоли он выводится по средством команды:

```
f = open ("list.txt")
```

Каким образом можно организовать поиск и вывод строки по его фрагменту?
(напр. ввожу «742», выдаёт «Ветеринарные услуги»

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myList = [
'742     Ветеринарные услуги',
'763     Сельско-хозяйственные кооперативные общества',
'780     Ландшафтные и садоводческие магазины',
'1520    Генеральные подрядчики - жилищное и торговое строительство',
'1711    Генеральные подрядчики по вентиляции, теплоснабжению, и водопроводу',
'1731    Подрядчики по электричеству',
'1740    Изоляция, мозаика, штукатурные работы, каменная кладка, облицовка плиткой'
]

myDict = dict( (i.split()[0], ' '.join(i.split()[1:])) for i in myList )

print( myDict.get(input("Введите код: ")))
Введите код: 742
Ветеринарные услуги
```

или так:

```
with open('D:/_Qt/list.txt') as f:
    myList = [ line for line in f ]

myDict = dict( (i.split()[0], ' '.join(i.split()[1:])) for i in myList )

while True:
    cod = input("Введите код или Enter для выхода: ")
    if cod == '':
        break
    print( myDict.get(cod))


Введите код или Enter для выхода: 742
Ветеринарные услуги
Введите код или Enter для выхода: 333
None
Введите код или Enter для выхода: 
>>>
```

Comment: @217323 Вы волшебник!!!!!!!!!!!

Как вам такой принцип построения...

Есть файл ***.txt, в котором программа будет искать значения построчно.
Если не ошибаюсь, принцип «grep» программа будет искать строки.
И запрос на ввод кода будет циклироваться?!

Comment: я добавил второй вариант в свой ответ.

Comment: @217323 .... Большое спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @217323 ..... Покажите, пожалуйста - как данный алгоритм можно поместить в UI.

Comment: @AlexandrS Публикуйте свой пример UI. Опишите что и куда вы хотите поместить и что у вас не получается. Но это уже тема для другого вопроса!

Comment: @217323

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/927798/python-3-7-qt-5-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-txt-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD