# Запрос на вывод информации из файла *.txt в выпадающее окно

Tags: python, gui, pyqt, qt-designer, qtablewidget

Есть файл-таблица (**`*.txt`**) и **`UI.py`** (скрин во вложении).

Не могу понять, что необходимо выполнить, чтобы инициировать поиск по файлу-таблице, а результат выводить в отдельное окно?

---

У программы есть две функции:

1. Пользователь вводит ключевое слово и ему выпадает значение в выпадающем окне.
2. Если пользователю необходимо увидеть файл-таблицу, он нажимает на кнопку "Показать весь список MCC" и открывается блокнот-файл: **`*.txt`**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UI.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(200, 200)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 200))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 200))
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("unnamed.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 141, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setText("")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 141, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 140, 111, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Segoe UI")
        font.setPointSize(7)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setFlat(True)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MCC Glossary"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите Ваш MCC:"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Показать весь\n"
" список МСС"))
```

**Console code**:

```
#Путь к файлу ***.txt
with open('D:\Mine application\MCC Glossary\mcc_list.txt') as f:
    myList = [ line for line in f ] #f = множество строк в файле-базе

#Словарь
myDict = dict( (i.split()[0], ' '.join(i.split()[1:])) for i in myList )

#Цикл
while True:
    cod = input("Введите код: \n")
    if cod == '':
        break
    print( myDict.get(cod))
```

**Example of list**:

```
742     Ветеринарные услуги
763     Сельско-хозяйственные кооперативные общества
780     Ландшафтные и садоводческие магазины
1520    Генеральные подрядчики - жилищное и торговое строительство
1711    Генеральные подрядчики по вентиляции, теплоснабжению, и водопроводу
1731    Подрядчики по электричеству
1740    Изоляция, мозаика, штукатурные работы, каменная кладка, облицовка плиткой
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        with open('D:/_Qt/list.txt') as f:
            myList = [ [line.split()[0], ' '.join(line.split()[1:])] for line in f ]
        rows    = len(myList)
        columns = 2

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self)
        self.table.setRowCount(rows)
        self.table.setColumnCount(columns)
        header = self.table.horizontalHeader()      
        header.setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

        for column in range(columns):
            for row in range(rows):
                item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(myList[row][column])  
                self.table.setItem(row, column, item)

        self.edit  = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.edit.setPlaceholderText('Введите ваш MCC')

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Найти', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def handleButton(self):
        items = self.table.findItems(
            self.edit.text(), QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly)
        if items:
            results = ''
            for item in items:
                results = results + 'MCC `{}`(r-{}, c-{}) - `{}`\n'.format(item.text(), 
                          item.row() + 1, 
                          item.column() + 1, 
                          self.table.item(item.row(), 1).text())

                self.table.setCurrentCell(item.row(), 1)
        else:
            results = 'Такого кода не существует.'

        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Результат поиска', results)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window() 
    window.resize(550, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Невероятно! Большое спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: maxsplit для слабаков)))

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


file_txt = """742     Ветеринарные услуги
763     Сельско-хозяйственные кооперативные общества
780     Ландшафтные и садоводческие магазины
1520    Генеральные подрядчики - жилищное и торговое строительство
1711    Генеральные подрядчики по вентиляции, теплоснабжению, и водопроводу
1731    Подрядчики по электричеству
1740    Изоляция, мозаика, штукатурные работы, каменная кладка, облицовка плиткой"""


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        myList = [line for line in file_txt.split('\n')]
        print(myList)
        self.myDict = dict( (i.split()[0], ' '.join(i.split()[1:])) for i in myList )
        print(self.myDict)

        self.setWindowTitle("QTextBrowser")
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 700, 300)

        label = QLabel('Введите ваш MCC')
        self.label_info = QLabel('')

        lineEdit = QLineEdit()
        lineEdit.textChanged[str].connect(self.run)

        button = QPushButton('Показать весь\n список MCC')
        button.clicked.connect(self.showList)

        self.text_document = QTextBrowser(self)
        self.text_document.setGeometry(0, 0, 700, 300)

        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(label, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(lineEdit, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.label_info, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(button, 3, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.text_document, 1, 3)

        # self.text_document.setHtml(html)

    def run(self, code):
        result = self.myDict.get(code)
        if result == None:
            self.label_info.setText("Такого кода не существует")
            return
        self.label_info.setText(result)

    def showList(self):
        self.text_document.setText(file_txt)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!!!!!!!!!!